# How to connect the mysql in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x

i am trying but not connect , and installing in pip install mysqlclient  getting `error_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'my_config.h': No such file or directory`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
you will configure your Django app to connect to MySQL. You will need to change the DATABASES dictionary to something along these lines:

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'myproject',
        'USER': 'myprojectuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using windows 7  and i am installing pip install mysqlclient   it get errors sir